# Closing fstream so files can be edited further in the code

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I'm trying to open and read a file, copy it's content while modifying it to another file, delete the original file and rename the temp file to the original name. The deletion and rename give a permission denied error because I don't know how to close the files before moving on with the code, please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strReplace = "5";
    string strNew = "4";
    ifstream filein("C:/test.txt"); //File to read from
    ofstream fileout("C:/test1.txt"); //Temporary file
    if(!filein || !fileout)
    {
        cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string strTemp;
    //bool found = false;
    while(filein >> strTemp)
    {
        if(strTemp == strReplace){
            strTemp = strNew;
            //found = true;
        }
        strTemp += "\n";
        fileout << strTemp;
        //if(found) break;
    }



    //remove original file
    if( remove( "C:/test.txt" ) != 0 )
    perror( "Error deleting file" );
    else
    puts( "File successfully deleted" );

    //rename temp file to original file
    char oldname[] ="C:/test1.txt";
    char newname[] ="C:/test.txt";

    int result= rename( oldname , newname );
    if ( result == 0 )
    puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
    else
    perror( "Error renaming file" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `close` on the stream object...?

Comment: Split your code inot seperate functions, each doing one thing, and you won't have this problem since an std stream gets closed when it goes out of scope. That, plus all the other benefits of dedicated functions

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will follow it

Answer (score 2):

Simply `filein.close()` and `fileout.close()`.  Reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/close/).

Comment: ermagerd thanks, can't believe it was that simple, I've searched but got lost in the complicated examples